# What is the difference between n output layers and 1 output layer with n neurons?

Tags: neural-networks

Suppose, I have 3 classes, 6 features. I need to generate 5 outputs.

What is the difference between 5 output layers with 1 neuron each, and 1 output layer with n neurons?

Answer (score 1):

If they use the same activation function the outcome is the same. The only real difference is in optimization, it is easier to run a single layer with $n$ neurons since it all boils down to a single matrix multiplication (or multiplication-add in case of bias). For $n$ output layers you would need to perform $n$ matrix multiplications.